# Uniform optimization ( - 1 values)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Consider following fragment shader:

```
uniform PolygonData
{
    int count;
    float points[1024];
} polygon;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    float j;
    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.count; ++i)
    {
            j = polygon.points[i++];
            j = polygon.points[i++];
            j = polygon.points[i++];
    }

    outColor = vec4(1, 1, j, 1);
}
```

Why is ***polygon.count*** and ***polygon.points*** optimized out?

Comment: Maybe because you don't use it for anything? You never initialize `points` in `polygon`. Your whole for loop does nothing but set `j` to be the same as the last `polygon.point[2]`, which is never set. So might as well delete the for loop and the result should be the same :)

Comment: @rozina How do you know they never set it?

Comment: @Ben The code does not include any initialization for it. Ofcouse I could be wrong, since this might be some OpenGL specifics here. Still I would expect initialization for polygon to be seen from code.

Comment: And how do you know they're optimised out?

Comment: @rozina Correct. My intention is to give this shader an array of floats and make a for loop computing something but i am not "directly" using those values in the shader. The color of fragment should be based on value that comes out of my magic _for_ loop. How can i pass values to fragment shader that they will not dissapear?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any OpenGL so I don't even know what a fragment shader is. If you just want to set the polygon.points you would do the same as any array I would guess. On a side note, I would question your for loop though. You seem to overwrite `j` with every line in the loop. Was that your intention?

Comment: Uniforms are initialised from a C program. That has nothing to do with it being optimised out.

Comment: Forget about the for loop. This loop is intended to return some value which will determine the final color.

Comment: How do you know it's getting optimised out?

Comment: Can you show the app code setting the uniform as well?

Comment: @Angew [My yesterday question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609998/pass-non-uniform-array-to-shader/)

Comment: Your entire for-loop can be translated to `j = polygon.points[polygon.count-1];` - which should be a single instruction in any decent shader compiler.

Comment: A couple of things: Have you checked that the shaders compile and link without errors? I't worth checking the logs for warnings as well (using `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog`). Also - do you mean to increment `i` in the loop body and the `for` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GuyRT

Yes. That was it. From there I got the ingormation that I was exceeding the maximum uniform array size.

This is what i was doing:

Vertex:

```
in vec3 inPosition;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Geometry:

```
layout(lines) in;
layout(triangle_strip) out;
layout(max_vertices = 4) out;

out vec3 worldPos;

uniform mat4 u_proj;

void main()
{

    vec4 pos0 = u_proj * gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    vec4 pos1 = u_proj * gl_in[1].gl_Position;

    //left up
    gl_Position.x = pos0.x;
    gl_Position.y = pos1.y;
    gl_Position.w = pos0.w;
    worldPos = gl_Position.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    //left down
    gl_Position = pos0;
    worldPos = gl_Position.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    //right up
    gl_Position = pos1;
    worldPos = gl_Position.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    //right down
    gl_Position.x = pos1.x;
    gl_Position.y = pos0.y;
    gl_Position.w = pos1.w;
    worldPos = gl_Position.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment:

```
struct PolyData
{
    int count;
    float points[256];
};

uniform PolyData p;

uniform mat4 u_proj;

in vec3 worldPos;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    float testx = worldPos.x;
    float testy = worldPos.y;

    bool c = false;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0, j = p.count - 4; i < p.count; j = i, i = i + 3)
    {
        vec4 i_vec = u_proj * vec4(p.points[i], p.points[i + 1], 0, 1.0);
        vec4 j_vec = u_proj * vec4(p.points[j], p.points[j + 1], 0, 1.0);

        if (  (i_vec.y >= testy) != (j_vec.y >= testy) && (testx <= (j_vec.x - i_vec.x) * (testy - i_vec.y) / (j_vec.y - i_vec.y) + i_vec.x))
            c = !c;
}

    if (c == true)
    {
        outColor = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        outColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

[image: result]

Thanks for all the help.